# User permission check only works first time after installation

Tags: android, kotlin, permissions, user-permissions

My application only shows permission dialog only first time after app has been installed.  If I close it and open again, it doesn't show request window. Even if I manually disable location permission or request permission window on clickEvent it doesnt work.

checkPermission:

```
private fun checkPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //permission not granted

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
            //show an explanation to the user
        } else {
            //request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
                    ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_CODE)
        }
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
                ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_CODE)
    }
}
```

onRequestPermissionsResult:

```
override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode: Int, permissions: Array<out String>, grantResults: IntArray) {
    when(requestCode){
        ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_CODE -> {
            if ((grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)) {
                //granted
            } else {
                //denied
            }
            return
        }
    }
}
```

I call `checkPermission` function on `onStart` and when I click icon.

Comment: you do not handle cases where user denied and/or blocks the permission. What do you expect to happen? You should learn to debug your code. I am 99.99% sure that it works fine, you just don't handle the cases

Comment: Why didn’t you write codes in show permission rationale block?

Comment: You have to handle all the stages of app permission requests.. If you do not, it will not ask again as you are facing..

Comment: I'm not sure if I get the question right, but you could use shared preferences to see on every start whether the request was already allowed or not.

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thank you for your answer.  I will try to debug my code and check which cases I didn't handle.

Comment: no need, I already told you in my first comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you left `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale` part empty so it is not requesting permission second time . In it show an alert dialog why you need permission and when user clicks Ok ask for permission again . As an alternate you can ask permission again directly.

```
private fun checkPermission(){
    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)
            != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        //permission not granted

        if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                        Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION)) {
             ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
                ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_CODE)
        } else {
            //request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                    arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
                    ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_CODE)
        }
    } else {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this,
                arrayOf(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION),
                ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION_CODE)
    }
}
```

You are not handling the deny and dont ask again cases properly , I would suggest you to use [this](https://github.com/nabinbhandari/Android-Permissions) library for simplicity . you will get all call backs at single place

```
  Permissions.check(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, null, new PermissionHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onGranted() {
        // do your task.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

when the user accepts your permission it accepts it permanently (unless the user remove it) check permission shows only when the permission is not granted yet. when the user clear data or uncheck the permission through setings->app settings-> chosen app->permisson.

Comment: *when the user accepts your permission it accepts it permanently* -- not true. Permissions can be manually revoked at any time

Comment: @TimCastelijns I didn't mean that maybe my English is not that good

Answer (score 0):

```
    private fun checkAndRequestPermissions(): Boolean {

    val permissionContact = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)

    val permissionPhoneState = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
            Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
    val permissionCamera = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
            Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    val permissionWriteExternal = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity,
            Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)

    val locationPermission = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    val listPermissionsNeeded = java.util.ArrayList<String>()
    when {
        locationPermission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
    }

    when {
        permissionContact != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
    }

    when {
        permissionPhoneState != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE)
    }
    when {
        permissionCamera != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.CAMERA)
    }
    when {
        permissionWriteExternal != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED -> listPermissionsNeeded.add(Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
    }
    when {
        !listPermissionsNeeded.isEmpty() -> ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, listPermissionsNeeded.toTypedArray(), REQUEST_ID_MULTIPLE_PERMISSIONS)
    }
    return true
}
```